# Error while installing HBase on windows

Tags: java, cygwin, installation, hbase

I’m very new in ssh world. It’s the first time I use Cygwin. I do it by using this man [hbase installing](http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html) When I Start HBase using the command ./bin/start-hbase.sh, got this error:
[image: Error while installing HBase on windows]

I create a link to jre home in c:\cygwin\jre7
And set it in ./conf/hbase-env.sh as java home:

```
   # The java implementation to use.  Java 1.7+ required.
    export JAVA_HOME=/jre7
```

and test java by this command:
[image]

then why I got this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You've got your `start-hbase.sh` in `DOS` EOL, just convert it to `UNIX` EOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your `start-hbase.sh` in `DOS` EOL, just convert it to `UNIX` EOL.